# Setting up Postfix to do SPF checks

Tags: server, email, postfix, mail

I'm trying to get our incoming mail set up to do SPF checks in hopes of cutting down on spoofed addresses. We run Postfix from the good old mail-stack-delivery package on Ubuntu 18.04. I followed this tutorial, but couldn't get it to work in the end: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix/SPF

What happens is that soon as I enable the policy in Postfix's main.cf and reload Postfix, messages start getting rejected. Looking at the logs, it's as if the policy file pointed to, `unix:private/policy-spf`, isn't even found. I've tried a couple of variations like adding a 'd' and using `unix:/usr/bin/policyd-spf` but nothing works.

Would anyone in a similar situation care to share a working config? Where did the tutorial go off the rails?

(FWIW, I went the Python route, not the Perl route.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like the right magic letters can be found in this tutorial: https://makeityourway.de/enabling-spf-sender-policy-framework-checking-on-postfix/

Specifically, the chunk that goes into master.cf should be:

```
policyd-spf  unix  -       n       n       -       0       spawn       user=policyd-spf argv=/usr/bin/policyd-spf
```

And then the part for main.cf should be:

```
check_policy_service unix:private/policyd-spf
```

Another thing to get into is what to do with the defaults in /etc/postfix-policyd-spf-python/policyd-spf.conf: https://www.flomain.de/2015/08/how-to-postfix-with-spf/

I am finding a lot of conflicting information. What I want is:

No SPF for the domain? Could just be a scrub sysadmin like me. *Accept the message.*

SPF for the domain, but the test fails? *OK, go ahead and reject.*

Why is email so hard?

Comment: I love to whinge. Here's some anti-whinging, suck-it-up-buttercup content instead:

Seems like the policy config I want is
`HELO_reject = Fail
Mail_From_reject = Fail

PermError_reject = False
TempError_Defer = False`

Details in the man pages: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/policyd-spf.conf.5.html

Also note that SPF_Not_Pass rejects 'neutral' results: https://serverfault.com/questions/791139/why-does-spf-not-pass-reject-on-neutral-result

Comment: Anti-whinging content here, forgot to get URL and paste it: https://poolp.org/posts/2019-08-30/you-should-not-run-your-mail-server-because-mail-is-hard/